# Do I need to declare all my citizenships to my broker or bank?

Tags: banking, broker

Do I need to declare all my citizenships to my broker or bank?

This is a follow up question  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/75069/can-one-of-my-citizenships-cause-problems-with-investing

Comment: Did you broker/bank ask for all your citizenships?

Comment: What country is the bank in?